# Can the lock screen in CM12 be set to show the keypad immediately on turning the screen on, instead of having to slide the padlock icon?

Tags: cyanogenmod, lock-screens, 5.0-lollipop

Yesterday I installed Cyanogenmod (NIGHTLY 20150128, Android version 5.0.2) on my Galaxy S5 (SM-G900F), and so far I'm very happy with it, except for one little annoyance. Having to slide the padlock icon to bring up the keypad on the lock screen. Is there a way to get rid of this? I want the keypad available immediately when I turn the screen on.

Answer (score -3):

In CM11 this happens when you tick the "maximize widgets" option in Lockscreen settings. Might be similar in CM12.

Comment: The closest thing I found is a setting whether to show notifications or not on the lock screen. It's not under lock screen settings, but under notifications. It has the options to show everything, hide sensitive content or hide everything. No matter which I select, I still have to slide the padlock. I still upvoted though, because the idea is sound.